# What is a good commercial tar stream lib for c# and .net?

Tags: c#, stream, tar

We are currently using SharpZipLib but since it uses the GPL we need to replace it with a commercial lib.

Comment: Note that #ziplib actually uses a MODIFIED GPL that allows you to "use this library in commercial closed-source applications" (quoted from the #ziplib web site). So if you are not allowed to use GPL, but ARE allowed to use open-source, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: On the other hand, if you aren't allowed to use open-source at all, then obviously you're still stuck.

Comment: Ya we sent the page that modified the GPL to the execs I am still looking at alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment about #ziplib on the main post... but if you really need a commercial product (not open-source), [IP*Works! Zip .NET](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/zip/technologies.aspx?sku=izn8-a) might fit the bill. It does have TAR support according to [this](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/tar.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip)?

It is not under the GPL, but rather the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL).

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI. There is an option to use BSD licensed library for tar reading/writing. Gzip compression and decompression you can do with build-in GZipStream from microsoft .NET 2.0

http://code.google.com/p/tar-cs/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tar library, there is a single-module implementation at

http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=Tar&file=Tar.cs

Comment: Link is broken.