# asp.net mvc zip uncompression support in dotnet libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc

does .net libraries give support for .zip uncompress operation?

Comment: See [Unzip files programmatically in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net), [.NET Library to unzip ZIP and RAR files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737/net-library-to-unzip-zip-and-rar-files), [
recommend a library/API to unzip file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023476/recommend-a-library-api-to-unzip-file-in-c), and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle zip streams through [GZipStream and DeflateStream](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/607172008133427PM/6.aspx) but for compressing and uncompressing multiple files you may take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).