# How to unzip compressed files using C#?

Tags: c#, zip

How can I use C# to unzip files? I've found that I have to use third-party libraries.  Is there any direct method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [recommend a library/API to unzip file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023476/recommend-a-library-api-to-unzip-file-in-c)

Comment: Disagree with voting to close this on the basis of being an exact dup, as it seems to be a slightly different variation on that question (recommend a system library vs recommend an external library) even though the answers end up overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace contains some compression classes such as [ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) but they are by no means as simple as using a third party libraries. I strongly recommend you to consider a third party library.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tool of the framework to zip and then to unzip

sinxe .NET 1.x you there are a lot of compession libraries out on the net, some are free some are commercial.
A great free library is #Zip, or the creator of the free C# IDE, #develop.

.NET Framework 2.0 has introduced GZipStream and DeflateStream classes for compression and decompression of streams. Here are links on MSDN:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream(VS.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for #ZipLib....been around for ever and still used all over the place.  good stuff...url is http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had great luck with the free [Iconic Zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.  It zips and unzips very quickly, works well and is small in size.  It also works with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

For **[zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29)** files, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) works great. Just one assembly is required for zip file support.

For **[gzip](http://www.gzip.org/)** files, you can use the streams in the [System.IO.Compression namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx), or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Note that if you have `*.tar.gz` or `*.tgz` files, you'll need something that speaks [tar(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) or [tar(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%208-current) as well.

For **[zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)** compressed data, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is your friend again. [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) uses the Deflate algorithm. I'm not sure if zlib[6](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) and [System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) are compatable, though.

There are other libraries that support these compression formats, but many of them, I believe, are wrappers around non-managed code. Whether that's a good or bad thing depends on your requirements.

DotNetZip is pure managed code. My tests show that it runs at about the same speed as the [Info-Zip's open-source zip/unzip](http://www.info-zip.org/) implementations. The resulting compressed files aren't byte-identical, but they are compatible and have approximately the same compression ratios.

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29). It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.5 has a more useful ZipPackage class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

It is still not real easy to use, the sample code in the class documentation is quite long.