# How can i extract the data that required from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all as per the requirement i am having i would like to extract the data from this site

http://loving1.tea.state.tx.us/lonestar/Menu_dist.aspx?parameter=101902

I would like to extract the data that was presented in grid how can i can any one help me

I tried this

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://loving1.tea.state.tx.us/lonestar/Menu_dist.aspx?parameter=101902");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
    string html = String.Empty;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
    {
        html = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

[image]

The gird data i would like to extract is in the image. Please help

Comment: Why don't you simply ask them where do they get the data from and request that data through an api that they might have, or you will probably run into legal issues here...

Comment: thre is Export To Excel action button, I believe you can export in Excel and then parse table or more straightforward way - read whole HTML page and parse it by finding specific table tag

Comment: I am unable to find the specified tag when i view source

Comment: How about using [Html Agility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way - download a page and parse HTML by finding out appropriate `<table>` tags, but in this way your "parser" has to be updated each time even HTML layout has been changed or whatever...

An other way is to  leverage "Export To..." feature which is kindly provided by the site, so you can simulate HTTP request using "Export to Excel 2007 button". The idea is Excel 2007 workbooks is a zip archive with an XML data files and CSS style sheets. So you would be able to load well-formed XML data file/multiple files.

Underlying URL:

`http://loving1.tea.state.tx.us/Common.Cognos/Secured/ReportViewer.aspx?reportSearchPath=/content/folder[@name='TPEIR']/folder[@name='LS']/package[@name='Districts and Schools']/report[@name='AAG5_Dist_Over']&ui.name=AAG5_Dist_Over&year=2010&district=101902&server=Loving1.tea.state.tx.us/lonestar`

then download `XLSX` file which is ZIP archive with embedded XML files

- *xl\worksheets\Sheet1.xml*
- *xl\workbook.xml*

so just unzip, load XML and enjoy it...

Comment: `@sll` so as per ur saying i have to save the xlsx and then read the required content from that right

Comment: @Vivekh : yep, basically 1) save XLSX 2) unzip ([use any of these libs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023476/recommend-a-library-api-to-unzip-file-in-c-sharp)) 3) load required XML files

Comment: Hi `Sll` a small question will i get the XLSX from the link u posted

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see exact URL whilst downoading a file (I believe you see Export button on top of the page)

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebClient.DownloadString("http://loving1.tea.state.tx.us/lonestar/Menu_dist.aspx?parameter=101902")` to get the data from the server.
And than use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the html.

Comment: As @Oded wrote, you can all do with agility pack... first download and then extract data with XPath